# JMeter Dashboard generation by Sampler prefix

Tags: jmeter

I'm running JMeter non GUI mode and generating dashboard and it's working,

Next step I wanted to add UUID to each sampler to make it easier to find my request in logs

So sampler names are: Login ${uuid} , operation1 ${uuid},...
while uuid variable set before.

In GUI mode it helps to find problems faster and easier.

When I execute the non GUI mode it failed on `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.`

Basically (I did a shorter test) it create a report with each login (and operation) separately, as

```
Login f9b9c9e9-15ac-4b96-a454-20d8fc7d8844  1   0   0.00%   622.00  622 622 622.00  622.00  622.00  1.61    0.60    0.90
Login f67871f5-f447-4125-85e7-981592d9bff2 ...
```

How can aggregate all logins/specific operation to a single result and prevent such exception in non GUI with dashboard execution?

Exception in log:

```
2018-01-17 09:06:17,302 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.AbstractGraphConsumer.addKeyData(AbstractGraphConsumer.java:352) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.AbstractGraphConsumer.stopConsuming(AbstractGraphConsumer.java:563) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer.stopProducing(AbstractSampleConsumer.java:241) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer.stopConsuming(FilterConsumer.java:112) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer.stopProducing(AbstractSampleConsumer.java:241) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer.stopConsuming(FilterConsumer.java:112) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer.stopProducing(AbstractSampleConsumer.java:241) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.NormalizerSampleConsumer.stopConsuming(NormalizerSampleConsumer.java:125) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.CsvFileSampleSource$PrivateProducer.stopProducing(CsvFileSampleSource.java:339) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.CsvFileSampleSource.produce(CsvFileSampleSource.java:185) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.CsvFileSampleSource.run(CsvFileSampleSource.java:238) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:244) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest.generateReport(JMeter.java:1198) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest.testEnded(JMeter.java:1134) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:230) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:498) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_05]
```

**EDIT**:

Try to add controller for each request and add to user.properties:

```
 jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(Login|O‌​peration1|Operation2‌​)(-success|-failure)‌​?$
```

I insert parent above all transaction with UUID and call Transaction controller in the name of the operation, as Login:
[image]

Still in dashboard (small execution) the operations are seen not as a group.

Now getting different error but still OutOfMemoryError:

```
2018-01-17 13:25:07,766 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3175) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:220) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:212) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:443) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.ListResultData.addResult(ListResultData.java:54) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.AbstractGraphConsumer.addKeyData(AbstractGraphConsumer.java:353) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.AbstractGraphConsumer.stopConsuming(AbstractGraphConsumer.java:563) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer.stopProducing(AbstractSampleConsumer.java:241) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer.stopConsuming(FilterConsumer.java:112) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer.stopProducing(AbstractSampleConsumer.java:241) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer.stopConsuming(FilterConsumer.java:112) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer.stopProducing(AbstractSampleConsumer.java:241) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.NormalizerSampleConsumer.stopConsuming(NormalizerSampleConsumer.java:125) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.CsvFileSampleSource$PrivateProducer.stopProducing(CsvFileSampleSource.java:339) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.CsvFileSampleSource.produce(CsvFileSampleSource.java:185) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.CsvFileSampleSource.run(CsvFileSampleSource.java:238) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:244) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest.generateReport(JMeter.java:1198) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest.testEnded(JMeter.java:1134) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:230) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:498) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_05]
```

Comment: When does OOM occur ? Do you have some heap dump available ? it would be interesting to share it for analysis

Comment: attached log. it is helpful?

Answer (score 0):

An option is to do the following:

- Add a Transaction Sampler as parent of Login ${UUID}

In user.properties, only include the parent Transaction name:

> jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(Search|Order)(-success|-failure)?$

You can use menu in jmeter:

[image: Help > Export Transaction names]

You may have to increase **-Xmx** and you should open an issue providing the Heap dump to jmeter for analysis, it could be a bug but it may just be due to number of different transactions.

Comment: If I have 5 operations: Login ,Operatio1, Operation2, I need to have Transaction controller and a line in user.properties for each ?

Comment: Yes, one parent TC for each and something like jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(Login|Operation1|Operation2)(-success|-failure)?$

Comment: Can you show how you configured  jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter and the structure of your test plan ?
Thanks

Comment: added to question